# How to make a custom content element containing header, bodytext, image from tt_content inline in TYPO3 / TCA overrides?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I want to get an array of custom content objects into my fluid template, so I can build an unordered List.

This is what I want to build:

[unordered list of li elements containing image, header, bodytext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duoZC.jpg)

In my backend I build a custom element like this:

[my custom content element with fields image, header, bodytext from tt_content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUlyO.png)

What I want to achieve is, that I have a container and in it I can have my custom content element.  When expanding it, I can add header, image and bodytext. So that i basically get an array of custom content Elements that I can loop over in my fluid template.

It should look like this:

[each entry should be my custom content element with image, header, bodytext when expanding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d32LL.png)

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [extension gridelements](https://packagist.org/packages/gridelementsteam/gridelements) to create a container that can hold unlimited content elements and use its template to loop over the partial which creates your content element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the TYPO3 way instead of using Grid Elements..

I see you already know how to make a custom content element. To make children within your content element you could make an extra SQL field xxx_foreign.

You need to make 2 content elements. The child you know how to make.
The TCA for the inline field of the parent and needed extra colPos in the backendLayout you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68691660/typo3-hide-colpos-for-irre-tt-content)

Then you will need in typoscript a [dataprocessor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing.html) I will give an example in which the child contains assets (media). In that case you need a nested solution:

```
        tt_content {
        xxx_education_block < lib.xxxCustomContentElements
        xxx_eheducation_block {
        templateName = xxxEducationBlock
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            10 {
                if.isTrue.field = xxx_educations
                table = tt_content
                pidInList.field = pid
                where = xxx_foreign=###uid### AND deleted=0 AND hidden=0
                orderBy = sorting
                markers {
                    uid.field = uid
                }
                as = xxxEducations

                dataProcessing {
                    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                    10 {
                        if.isTrue.field = assets
                        references {
                            fieldName = assets
                        }
                        as = assets
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To add this to the content wizard:

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.blocks {
header = Xxx blokken
after = common

elements {

    xxx_education_block {
        iconIdentifier = content-bullets
        title = XXX - Education intro block
        description =  Introblock xxx
        tt_content_defValues {
            CType = xxx_education_block
        }
    }
}

show := addToList(xxx_education_block)
}
```

If you do a debug in Fluid you should now be able to iterate over the children and the assets of the children.